# Unexpected token error in an Angular Chrome app for ng-include

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am getting the following error for ng-include

```
    Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 17 of the expression [chrome-extension://iikdmhjdakcicmdogkpcfcnlmacgggnj/templates/profile.html] 
starting at [://iikdmhjdakcicmdogkpcfcnlmacgggnj/templates/profile.html]
```

I have added the profile.html in the manifest and can access it via the url chrome-extension://iikdmhjdakcicmdogkpcfcnlmacgggnj/templates/profile.html

What could be the reason for this? Please let me know how to fix this?

EDIT:

I have tried referencing the template file by both

```
<div ng-include="'+chrome.extension.getURL("templates/profile.html")+'">
```

and

```
<div ng-include="/templates/profile.html" ></div>
```

Comment: Please don't forget to include the code that produces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is how your ng-include looks like:

```
<ng-include src="chrome-extension://iikdmhjdakcicmdogkpcfcnlmacgggnj/templates/profile.html"></ng-include>
```

If it is true that  you included "chrome-extension://+extensionId" in the url, remove it. Let the ng-include look like this:

```
<ng-include src="/templates/profile.html"></ng-include>
```

Also, include the "/templates/profile.html" in the manifest's [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources), like this:

```
//manifest
{
  ...
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "/templates/profile.html"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Getting the error  Syntax Error: Token 'templates' is an unexpected token at column 2 of the expression [/templates/profile.html] starting at [templates/profile.html] :|

Comment: Please share the surrounding lines of code where this error happens.